# Interpretation of Standard Deviation independent of the distribution?

Tags: probability

Is there any intuitive way to interpret the standard deviation regardless of the probability distribution?

So for example, for the normal distribution, I know how to interpret being within 1 standard deviation - there is a a 68% of being there. For other distributions I can calculate this probability as well.

But if I don't know the distribution, how is it a meaningful statistic? Is it only meaningful in relation to other random variables that we *know* follow the same distribution, but have a different standard deviation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard deviation measures dispersion of a random variable regardless of the distribution.  [Chebyshev's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) states that *any* random variable (whether normally distributed or not) takes values more than $k$ standard deviations from the mean with probability less than $\frac1{k^2}$.

For example, it is true for any distribution that at most $\frac19$ of the values are more than 3 standard deviations from the mean.  Or turning it around, for any random variable, at least half the values lie in the range $(\mu - \sqrt2\sigma, \mu +\sqrt2 \sigma)$.

In most cases, the Chebyshev bound is extremely loose, and more of the distribution is closer to the mean than it would suggest.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Please see my followup question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999984/is-there-of-list-of-probability-distributions-ranked-by-tightness-of-fit-for-a