# Is there of list of probability distributions ranked by "tightness of fit" for a given SD?

Tags: probability

Given the mean and standard deviation of a distribution, [we know from Chebyshev's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999912/interpretation-of-standard-deviation-independent-of-the-distribution) that at least a half of the values will be between between ($\mu - \sqrt{2}\sigma, \mu + \sqrt{2}\sigma$).

If you know the distribution, you can say more than that. E.g. if you know the distribution is normal, you can say the probability of being within 1 standard deviation is 68%. Had we not know nothing about that interval.

Is there a list of distributions categorized by how "tight" the distribution is given a SD? Obviously this depends on the point on the interval, e.g. some distributions have heavier tails than other.

Comment: [How to format mathematics on this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @MJD Thanks, edited.